# Can you overload Sum to add custom types

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a Money struct that has currency and amount. I would like to be able to sum an List by using linq.

```
public struct Money
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public static Money operator +(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        if (m1.Currency != m2.Currency)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return new Money() { Amount = m1.Amount + m2.Amount, Currency = m1.Currency };
    }
}
```

Given the above code if I have a list of Items that have Money value objects is it possible to get the Sum function to work with a Money value object.

ie

```
Items.Sum(m => m.MoneyValue);
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like your + will not be 100% happy with the MiscUtil generic sum, due to the use of `default(T)`; I wonder if you should change `Money` to be more generous - i.e. `someValue + default(Money) => someValue`

Comment: Also - mutable struct; *awoooga*, *awoooga*...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
public static class SumExtensions
{
    public static Money Sum(this IEnumerable<Money> source)
    {
        return source.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
    }

    public static Money Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Money> selector)
    {
        return source.Select(selector).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Money> moneys = ...
Money sum = moneys.Sum();
```

and

```
IEnumerable<Transaction> txs = ...
Money sum = txs.Sum(x=>x.Amount);
```

Comment: can you please also provide the usage of these methods?

Comment: you're probably gonna want to make that class public. took me a minute to realize why mine wasn't compiling (defined in different DLL)

Comment: [This is causing probems for me...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640030/bad-overload-resolution-of-extension-method)

Comment: To avoid exceptions from `Aggregate` when `source` is empty or `selector` doesn't return anything, use `DefaultIfEmpty` before `Aggregate`, e.g. `source.DefaultIfEmpty().Aggregate((x, y) => x + y)` or `source.Select(selector).DefaultIfEmpty().Aggregate((x, y) => x + y)`

Answer (score 3):

Operators are a pain. However, if you look at [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/), I have implemented a generic `Enumerable.Sum` that *does* respect custom operators. The usage is (intentionally) identical - so your line:

```
var moneySum = Items.Sum(m => m.MoneyValue);
```

should work, with the expected result - **except** that you don't currently handle `default(Money)` for addition purposes. Alternatively, if this is **just** for `MoneyValue`, just write an extension method:

```
public static class MoneyExtensions {
    public static Money Sum(this IEnumerable<Money> source) {
        Money sum = source.First();
        foreach(var item in source.Skip(1)) sum += item;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Actually, to avoid 2 enumerations, I might tweak this to:

```
using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (!iter.MoveNext()) return default(Money);
    var sum = iter.Current;
    while (iter.MoveNext()) sum += iter.Current;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old. But I have a similar Money class in my system where I do this.
I've changed my Sum implementation to the way Jesper is doing it.

I don't have a `default` for money, but what I did to resolve the cases of empty collections was add the seed of the aggregate.

```
public static class SumExtensions
{        
    public static Money Sum(this IEnumerable<Money> source)
        => source.Aggregate(new Money(0), (x, y) => x + y);

    public static Money Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Money> selector)
        => source.Select(selector).Sum();
}
```

My implementation handles adding Monies without currencies. Any other cases will throw a DifferentCurrenciesException.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you return `m.MoneyValue.Amount` instead - there's [a set of `Sum` overloads that accept a `Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549046.aspx).

Unfortunately `Sum` doesn't obey any `operator+` that you define. (In fact, it couldn't call `operator+` without using reflection.)

Comment: The OP should be aware though that this will not take different currencies in the list into account.